# Dinamically add textboxes to a scrollviewer and retrieve data from them

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I'm developing a windows phone app that represents a recipe book, so on the "add recipe" page I would like to add dinamically two textboxes representing ingredient name and quantity if the user decides to add a new ingredient. 
My idea is to put the textboxes in a scrollviewer element, but I can't figure out how to add them dinamically from code and also how to retrieve data from the added textboxes: how can I name them so that I can retrieve data and exactly know which ingredient was added first, which second, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollviewer does not have a property to directly add elements such as stackpanel and grid which can directly add another element as child.
But Content property of Scrollviewer can be used to achieve this.

Add the two textboxes to the Grid(ContentPanel) firest and then set Grid as content to the scrollviewer

In code behind:

```
TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.Name = "Name";
            tb1.Text = "Ingredient Name";

            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.Name = "Quantity";
            tb2.Text = "Ingredient Quantity";

            Grid gd = new Grid();
            gd.Children.Add(tb1);
            gd.Children.Add(tb2);

            sc1.Content = gd;
```

In Window1.xaml

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="sc1">

        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Ok, but I have to do this everytime the user wants to add a new ingredient, so how can I do that whenever the user clicks on the "add ingredient" button? I should add two new textboxes everytime the user wants to add a new ingredient, so how can I manage the naming for the textboxes so that I can retrieve data from each of them?

Comment: create and declare TextBoxes globally. Then you can access the textbox object anywhere. and there is no need to create new textboxes everytime. you can just change the "Text" property of the textboxes